# Bounding Integral Involving Riemann Zeta

Tags: number-theory, contour-integration, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

For $2 \le T \le x$, can we bound
$$\int_1^{1+\frac{1}{log x}}\frac{x^s}{s}\zeta(\sigma + iT) \, \mathrm{d}\sigma \ll \frac{x \log^3 x}{T}$$

---

**Question Background**

> [image: Part (i)]

We get the expression for $Z(s)$ by writing the Dirichlet series corresponding to $\mu \star (\frac{\mu^2 \phi}{\text{id}})$ as an Euler product.

We then note that $Z(s)$ converges absolutely for $\mathfrak{R}(s) > \frac12$

**Main Part of Question**

> [image: Part (iii)]

We aim for the above expression by considering the contour integral over the rectangle with corners at $(\frac12 + \epsilon \pm iT)$, $(c \pm iT)$.

The first term on the *RHS* is just the residue of the $\frac{x^s}{s} \zeta(s) Z(s)$ at its pole at $s = 1$.

The first error term on the *RHS* bounds the integral along the left vertical path (from $(\frac12 + \epsilon + iT)$ to $(\frac12 + \epsilon - iT)$).

The *LHS* and the second error term on the *RHS* just comes from part (i), which is the integral over the right vertical path.

However, I am a bit stuck on how to bound the horizontal integrals. Specifically, for $\sigma \le 1$, we can bound $\zeta(\sigma + iT) \ll |T|^{1-\sigma} \log|T|$; this leaves the part of the horizontal integral from $\sigma = 1$ to $\sigma = c = 1 + \frac{1}{log x}$, on which I am stuck as I am unsure of how to bound $\zeta(\sigma + i T)$. (The other terms are easy to bound on this part of the path - $Z(s) \le Z(\frac12 + \epsilon) = \mathcal{O}(1)$, for example.)

We need to bound the horizontal integrals by either of the two error terms; it seems, that we stand more chance of bounding it by the second error term, $\mathcal{O}(\frac{x \log^3 x}{T}), and in order to do this, it seems that we need

$$\int_1^{1+\frac{1}{log x}}\frac{x^s}{s}\zeta(\sigma + iT) \, \mathrm{d}\sigma \ll \frac{x \log^3 x}{T}$$

---

**Edit:** Based on the comment by Daniel Fischer, it seems that we have $\zeta(\sigma + iT) = \mathcal{O}(\log T)$ on $\sigma > 1$ (and obviously this suffices for the purposes of the original question).

**Edit 2:** As explained by Daniel Fischer in the comments, this bound is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853759/riemann-zeta-function-is-big-oh-of-logt).

Comment: For $\sigma \geqslant 1$ you have an $O(\log T)$ bound for $\zeta(\sigma + iT)$. Then the direct estimate gives you an $O\bigl(\frac{x\log T}{T\log x}\bigr)$ bound. Since $T \ll x$ that's even $O(x/T)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! Could you just direct me to where this bound comes from? The best I could do was to (very naively) bound it by either $\mathcal{O}(T^3)$ or by $\frac1{\sigma - 1}$. (I'm sure I'm probably missing something kinda obvious!)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853759/riemann-zeta-function-is-big-oh-of-logt) is an explanation. The bound is, iirc, due to Mellin.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have looked at the question you linked, but although the title of the question seems identical, the answer doesn't seem to show that $\zeta(\sigma + iT) = O(\log T)$ for $\sigma \ge 1$ - am I missing something?

Comment: The first parts establish $$\zeta(\sigma + it) = \sum_{n \leqslant \lvert t\rvert} \frac{1}{n^{\sigma + it}} + O(1)$$ for, say, $\lvert t\rvert \geqslant 2$ and $\sigma > c$, where $c > 0$ can be chosen arbitrarily small. So it remains to see that the sum is $O(\log t)$. That is done separately for $\sigma < 1$, where $\sigma \geqslant 1 - \frac{a}{\log \lvert t\rvert}$ is used, and for the case $\sigma \geqslant 1$, which is the very last thing in the answer. For $\sigma \geqslant 1$ we have

Comment: $$\biggl\lvert\sum_{n \leqslant \lvert t\rvert} \frac{1}{n^{\sigma + it}}\biggr\rvert \leqslant \sum_{n \leqslant \lvert t\rvert} \frac{1}{n^{\sigma}} \leqslant \sum_{n \leqslant \lvert t\rvert} \frac{1}{n} \leqslant 1 + \log \lvert t\rvert\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah! Of course! Thanks for the direction